# what is the need of setting <autocommit> in solrconfig.xml

Tags: mysql, solr

What is the benefit of setting autocommit in solrconfig.xml.
i read somewhere that these settings control how often pending updates will be automatically pushed to the index.
does it mean if solr server is running then it  automatically starts indexing process if it finds any updates in database???

Answer (score 1):

> does it mean if solr server is running then it automatically starts indexing process if it finds any updates in database???

If/when the update of the solr/lucene-index starts, depends on the configuration.
The number of new documents have to reach an watermark, after the auto commit runs.
It's also possible to define an time interval for starting the autocommit.

```
<autoCommit>
  <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs> <!-- maximum uncommited docs before autocommit triggered -->
  <maxTime>86000</maxTime> <!-- maximum time (in MS) after adding a doc before an autocommit is triggered -->
</autoCommit>
```

Look at this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#Update_Handler_Section